# The perfect client to test php web service

Tags: php, web-services, client-server, client

i'm developing a web service using **php**, this web service has to take a *request* information from a **client** and send it to the **server** then take the *response* from the **server** and send it back to the **client**, this **client** is not available right now so i want to use like a *virtual client* or *any other client* to depend on while developing that service, what's the best suitable thing for that case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The elitetists will probably say wget or curl. But get something with a GUI just for the sake of ease, the novelty of a black screen and white text runs out quite quickly.

I use a chrome plugin called "REST Console". Gives you all the options you need and is my "go to" app for messing around with API's.

There are other chrome plugins that do the same, just use the google store and look for a "rest console" and a few should come up.

There are standalone applications which are packed full of features which you will probably never use. But i don't see the point in over complicating things.

Comment: I prefer the "Postman - REST Client"-Extension for Google Chrome.

Comment: yep i got that one too, they all do pretty much the same core thing. I find the Rest Console interface to be quicker and simpler to use, but that's just down to what im used to. Postman has a good few additional features, so it's definitely worth a look too. "Advanced Rest Client" is another good one too (not as user friendly, but has the odd feature that makes up for it, especially if your working in a team)